# i am unable to select by clicking on checkbox datagrid mui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

When i click on checkbox it is not working neither selecting row nor deselecting row. If i click on other column then its working fine. Below is my datagrid and passed props.

this is data comming from server

```
data = [
    {
        "id": "cllz5tl0n0005bsjk7lll42dm",
        "name": "marketing",
        "departmentId": "D1809631",
        "deleted": false,
        "deletable": true,
        "createdBy": "cb02d938-ced0-4439-9578-68866cf48e0c",
        "companyId": "cllp33h3l0001bsq4agox7mo8",
        "userId": "cb02d938-ced0-4439-9578-68866cf48e0c",
        "createdAt": "2023-08-31T12:46:09.575Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-08-31T12:46:09.575Z"
    }
]
```

This is the columns data

```
columns = [
        {
            "field": "departmentId",
            "headerName": "Department ID",
            "width": 300,
            "check_status": true
        },
        {
            "field": "name",
            "headerName": "Department Name",
            "width": 300,
            "check_status": true
        },
        {
            "field": "createdAt",
            "headerName": "Created On",
            "width": 200,
            "check_status": true
        },
        {
            "field": "updatedAt",
            "headerName": "Updated On",
            "width": 200,
            "check_status": true
        }
    ]
```

this is our datagrid

```
       `<DataGrid
        className="dataList"
        rows={data}
        getRowHeight={() => "auto"}
        columns={columns ? columns : header_data}
        sx={{
            [`& .${gridClasses.cell}`]: {
              py: 1,
            },
          }}
        paginationMode="server"
        onPageChange={handlePageChange}
        rowsPerPageOptions={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 25, 50, 100]}
        checkboxSelection ={true}
        onSelectionModelChange={(ids: any) => {
          console.log("selection",ids);
          value_update("selected_data", ids);
        }}
        {...data}
        disableColumnSelector
        getCellClassName={() => 'truncate_text'} 
      />`
```

Comment: you have not shared enough code to reproduce the issue.